# Sharepoint Online - powershell cmdlet update-usertype - Exception

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

when I run this command:

```
update-usertype -LoginName *username*
```

I get the following error message. However, I do not know what this means.

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

I am using the latest Sharepoint Online Library and at the moment of execution I am global admin including owner on every sharepoint site.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I can reproduce your problem.

[image]

We recommend that you sign in **Azure Active Directory admin center** as an administrator and directly modify the "**User type**" of the user account.

[image]

======================= **Updated Answer** =========================

After my test, after a period of time (within 24 hours), the SharePoint user's usertype will be updated automatically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought this was a special Sharepoint topic. Because updating on the user in Azure is not easily updated in Sharepoint. The user has already the right user type in azure. But in shareppoint the user still have another user type (guest). And this makes some problems with the site permissions

Comment: Hi, patchfox. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I tried your suggestion. The problem still exists. Command not working and User has the old user type

Comment: UPDATE: i tested the scenario on another tenant. There is only one sharepoint site and minimal permission assignments. On this tenant, the command works fine. So, could it be, that the user who trigger the command needs collection administrator for all sites of sharepoint?

Comment: Hi, patchfox. Yes, you are right. The user who triggered the command needs SharePoint Administrator permission.